# Selecting enabled rows with ClientSelectColumn

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik

I have a telerik GridClientSelectColumn along with `AllowMultiRowSection` set to `true` for selecting all rows.  So on the server side, some of the rows are disabled, but when I go ahead click the button, it will select all the rows regardless the button is being enabled/disabled.

So I figured I can loop through all the rows on client side using jquery and see if they are disabled previously and if so I will mark them as unchecked during `OnRowSelected`.

But I am not sure how to go about it, I have a RadGrid, a MasterTableView and several GridBoundColumn.

I mainly don't know how to select all the items from the radgrid and check whether each one was disabled previously.

Any tips would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

check the following telerik help documentation which mentions about getting Cell Values for Selected Rows Client-side

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-getting-cell-values-for-selected-rows-client-side.html

Hope this really helps you..